# Angular toggle switch issue on duplicated form group

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a form group that has several form controls within it, including a toggle switch. The toggle switch changes a boolean value in the model to true or false. Dependent upon the value, there is an *ngIf that handles if form controls are displayed or not. This all currently works fine, however I have a requirement to actually basically clone the entire form group, which I have achieved. However, the toggle switch only works on the first form group, and none of the rest. And actually, if I click the toggle on the others it actually toggles just the first one on and off...what am I missing here?

Here is how it looks, I actually clicked the 2nd toggle switch:
[image]

The model has this value:

```
advancedOptions: boolean;
```

The template is like so:

```
<div class="advancedOptions">              
        <div class="service-group jbh-toggle">
          Advanced Options:
          <label class="toggleLabel inline-block" for="inbond-freight">Hide</label>
          <input class="jbh-toggle-checkbox ng-untouched ng-valid ng-dirty" #advancedOptions id="handlingUnitAdvancedOptionsToggle" type="checkbox" 
          (change)="handlingUnitAdvancedOptionsToggle(advancedOptions.checked)">              
          <label class="jbh-toggle-label" for="handlingUnitAdvancedOptionsToggle">
          <span class="jbh-toggle-inner" id="span-toggleInner3"></span>
          <span class="jbh-toggle-switch" id="span-toggleSwitch3"></span>
          </label>
          <label class="toggleLabel inline-block" for="handlingUnitAdvancedOptionsToggle">Show</label>
        </div>
      </div>
```

The *ngIf is simply:

```
<div *ngIf="advancedOptions"></div>
```

All the other controls work fine in the duplicated form group, except for the toggle switch.

Comment: Are you really duplicating the `handlingUnitAdvancedOptionsToggle` id?

Comment: hmm yes...sounds like this could be part of the issue...but removing the id breaks the whole thing worse

Comment: You are also using the same local variable (`advancedOptions`) for each. That might also cause some issues based upon what `handlingUnitAdvancedOptionsToggle()` does with that variable.

Comment: hmm can you think of an alternative? just wanting the toggle to hide a div dependent upon status

Comment: It seems, logically to me at least, that if you have say Adv Options 1, Adv Options 2, and Adv Options 3, and you want individual controls to control them each independent of one another, that you would use a component state variable for each one. As the state variable gets flipped, *ngIf activates for the _corresponding_ Adv Options. But there are many ways to solve every issue.

Comment: Sure, glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use your formcontrol value of toggle switch like when it's value is true then you can show/hide like below
`form.controls.default_checkbox.value != 1`

Comment: That would work on a single toggle switch, but I am cloning the toggle and form group